# Encurtar URL de rastreamento do Google Analytics (somente as variáveis)

Tags: php, wordpress, url, google, redirecionamento-de-url

Gostaria de encurtar uma URL do meu site WordPress da seguinte forma:

```
www.meusite.com/?utm_source=FONTE&utm_medium=MEDIUM&utm_campaign=CAMPANHA
```

para algo como

```
www.meusite.com/?urlencurtada
```

Onde a **`?urlencurtada`** receberá todo o parâmetro da `?utm_source=FONTE&utm_medium=MEDIUM&utm_campaign=CAMPANHA`

O motivo disto é que quero compartilhar links no meu site ocultado essa extensa quantidade de variáveis do Analytics para um apelido que as execute ao ser chamado.

exemplo como desejo que fique:

```
www.meusite.com/umlinkquepassaseguranca/?urlencurtada
www.meusite.com/?urlencurtada
www.meusite.com/umamateriaLimpanaURL/?urlencurtada
www.meusite.com/um-artigo-com-endereco-enorme/?urlencurtada
```

assim vai ficar tem melhor que algo como:

```
www.meusite.com/um-artigo-com-endereco-enorme/?urlencurtada
```

ao invés de:

```
www.meusite.com/um-artigo-com-endereco-enorme/?utm_source=FONTE&utm_medium=MEDIUM&utm_campaign=CAMPANHA
```

O objetivo disto é fazer um rastreamento mantendo a elegância da url. Isso vai influenciar no compartilhamento da mesma, e na segurança que passará para quem as ver..

Comment: Talvez possa enfocar mais a pergunta conferindo estas duas tags no wp.se: [endpoints](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/endpoints) e [url-rewriting](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/url-rewriting). O problema é que agora já tem uma resposta e se mudar a pergunta não pode deixar a resposta inválida, se isso for acontecer tem que criar uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia usar um GET e Redirect junto, Desta forma:

www.meusite.com/?encurtador=1

No php:

```
<?php
 if (!empty($_GET['encurtador']) {

   if($_GET['encurtador'] == 1) { header("location:www.meusite.com/?utm_source=FONTE&utm_medium=MEDIUM&utm_campaign=CAMPANHA");  }

}
?>
```

Comment: a dica é boa mas isso tinha que ser capturado bem antes do `$_GET`, tipo no `init`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24187090/1287812